# How to perform conditional Rendering using word api in officejs

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I want to perform **conditional** rendering in Word. With the click of a hide button, I want to **hide** the selected text. and on the show, the hidden text should be visible again.
How can I perform the conditional rendering in word using officejs?
[image]

Comment: This question could use some code. Try some experiments in Script Lab with the [Font.hidden](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.font?view=word-js-preview#word-word-font-hidden-member) property.

Comment: Hidden property is not for the production Environment it's only for development preview.